# How to set up BizTalk WCF-WebHttp Send Port for POST method

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am working with a REST API within BizTalk Server 2013 and I need to make a POST to send an SMS using WCF-WebHttp Send Port. Content-Type is application/json.
I have so far put in the Address (URI) something like the following:

```
https://sendsms.com?
```

and in the HTTP Method and URL Mapping section I have something like:

```
<BtsHttpUrlMapping>
   <Operation Method="POST" Url="mobile={mobile}&amp;text={text}"/>
</BtsHttpUrlMapping>
```

I need to retrieve these 2 parameters from a SQL table (table simply contains mobile column and text column). This is where I'm unsure about what needs to be done as I've seen different ways of making POST method calls.

Could I create a receive port that polls the database to retrieve the row and promote these as context properties for the variable mapping?

Or do I need to create a Http Request Body schema to generate a request xml object?

Comment: Yes, those items need to be promoted properties so you can use the variable mapping

Comment: In what scenarios would you choose to create a Http Request schema instead of just using variable mapping in the Send Port config? Or is this just an alternative method that does the same thing?

Comment: The variable mapping uses promoted properties, so at the very least you needs a Property Schema with fields with MessageContextPropertyBase if you don't have a request schema.

Comment: Regarding using a request xml body vs query string URL would depend on the API you are calling.  Usually with POST or UPDATE you would be using a XML body, but for GET and DELETE you would most likely use a query string.  Although sometimes you use both a xml body and a query string.